# CSS Replace the external border to INTERNAL border

Tags: html, css, height, width, border

Is there any trick to make the css border internal and NOT external.
for example in that case the box size equals to 303px (and not 300px as I want to).
I do NOT want to set the width to 300px-3px = 297px;
I was wondering if there is quick solution without manipulate the width height.

the html :

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

the css :

```
div {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
div.a {
border: 3px solid red;
}
```

the jsFiddle :)

http://jsfiddle.net/nFLeG/1/

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use box-sizing to do this.

```
#someElement {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Fiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nFLeG/3/)

[Read more about box-sizing](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use:

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

I've updated your fiddle so you can check it out
http://jsfiddle.net/nFLeG/2/

You can read more about box-sizing over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).